# "-198 Serial voting [of someone else] was reversed"

Tags: bug

this is literally *"erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system"*, so i am calling it a **bug**.

what happened?  why did it happen?  what is the justification for it happening?

[image]
[image]
[image]

i don't really need or care about the points of rep.  but i am offended.

-- r b-j

Comment: Hi, it was me! I am one of the highest upvoting members (as can be seen from the voters section) but incidentally while reading one of your posts, saw that I had forgotten to upvote most of your 500+ great answers. So I decided to correct most of them that I found useful, so the system apparently false triggered for it being as an **targetted**? or a *robot*... No it was me.

Answer (score 7):

This is a matter of targeted voting - AKA "[serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/284336)".

Our network expects users to vote for posts based on their merits, not based on who wrote the post. When someone goes on a massive voting spree for a specific user, which is what happened in this case, those votes are generally caught by the system and automatically reverted.

You were given 20 upvotes within a very short period of time - 15 minutes - by the same user. This is clear targeted voting and not OK, so it was reverted by the system.

You (or anyone) can see the timing of the votes in your [reputation history](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/4346/robert-bristow-johnson?tab=reputation) on your profile:

[image: Screenshot of reputation changes from September 23, 2018 showing many upvotes in a short period of time.]

We have no way of knowing why someone voted this way but we like to assume they're doing it as a "thank you so much for your work" effort. Even then, this isn't acceptable behavior.

If someone wants to thank you for your help, they need to use the bounty system, which has the added bonus of allowing you to earn additional reputation that day because bounties aren't counted as part of the reputation cap.

Comment: Hi! That's me and definetely it was not a targeting operation. I just **speeded it up** a little ;-) I have upvoted multiple thousands of time here and a mere 20 shall not be considered as a targeting act, even if it was in an apparently short time interval. Just a little faster than I usually do. So how fast sets the trigger?

Comment: Like it says **you** are a **new contributor** ;-)

Comment: @Fat32 Please don't try to invalidate what I'm saying because I'm a "New contributor". What you did is something that our system *does not allow*. We expect users to vote for content based on the **content**, not who posted it. Going through someone's profile and systematically upvoting their posts is not acceptable behavior and will be reverted. Please don't repeat this action in the future.

Comment: oh no I said *new contributor* (according to the rules) to you to show you that the **rules** sometimes do not make sense :-)

Comment: So what's the trigger limit ?

Comment: @Catija, if i could downvote your comment, i would.  it shows evidence that you don't *"get it"*.

Answer (score 4):

It means that someone upvoted lots of your posts without voting so much for anyone else. The SE algorithms flag this and reverse any votes so detected.

Comment: well, it wasn't a sock puppet of me.  and, to use a Wikipedia term, i doubt it was a meat puppet.

Comment: the SE algorithm should be fixed.

Comment: Clarification: the relevant logic here makes no effort to detect sockpuppets (there are other scripts for that). It just detects targeted voting (see Catija's answer) - the intent is to discourage widespread voting that is not predicated on the usefulness of the post being voted on to the voter, and also applies to downvotes.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks! Edited to make remove that reference.

Comment: Hi Peter! I did it. Instead of 20 upvotes in 20 days I did it in 1 day ;-) There are 500+ answers of him all of which I'm interested in and I saw that Ihaven't upvoted already. People here do not like upvoting :-) You know from time to time I make fast actions (like deleting lots of my posts that I do not like). So now I have to upvote him slowly ;-)

Comment: @Fat32 :D Bold boy!